# Trying to pg_restore from a pg_dump file, FOREIGN TABLEs are causing probems: ERROR: server "<name>" does not exist,

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, pg-restore

Here is the output from the log. This happens hundreds of times then it hangs.

Command I'm running:

```
pg_restore -h $upgrade_db_host -U $upgrade_db_user -d $upgrade_db_name --no-privileges --no-owner --clean feb20_full_backup.sql
```

the backup file is created by

```
pg_dump -U $db_user -h $db_host -d $db_name -Fc > file_name.sql
```

And then the error

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 714; 1259 787746527 FOREIGN TABLE user_auths fake_schema
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  server "suinfo_database_server2" does not exist
    Command was: CREATE FOREIGN TABLE startupinfo.user_auths (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    user_id integer,
    authentication_p...
```

I've tried searching for errors related to "server does not exist" and Foreign Table stuff specifically, but haven't found anything that works.

Anything I am missing to get pg_restore to handle foreign tables?

Comment: Is that the first error which occurs?

Comment: No, looks like there are others including "index does not exist" errors. Googling that I found: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203142/pg-restore-error-relation-does-not-exist-and-creating-new-database

I think the -d argument may be the issue -- trying again. I'll update if it works.

Comment: What happens if you restore to a new (empty) database, and omit the `--clean` option on the pg_restore?

Comment: so the -d didn't work because then pg_restore just writes a .sql script to run from psql and i ran out of diskspace lol

Trying per your advice to a fresh/newly created db 'test_db'
```pg_restore -h $upgrade_db_host -U $upgrade_db_user -C  -d test_db --no-privileges --no-owner feb20_full_backup.sql```

Same issue -- same errors :(

Comment: all of the errors i can see mention "FOREIGN TABLE"

Comment: If you manually create the empty database to restore into, you should not use `-C` either.  You should save the errors to a file `2> errors` then search it for messages about CREATE SERVER failing.